# Update database using partial view in Modal

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a partial view that is strongly typed named "ChangePassword.cshtml" as so:

```
@model WebApplication1.Models.ViewModel.ChangeUserPassword

@{
    Layout = null;
}

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>


@using (Html.BeginForm("ChangePassword", "Account"))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="col_full">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.OldPassword, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "capitalize t600" })
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.OldPassword, null, new { @class = "sm-form-control", id = "txtOldPassword" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.OldPassword)
        </div>

        <div class="col_full">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ChangedPassword, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "capitalize t600" })
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ChangedPassword, null, new { @class = "sm-form-control", id = "txtChangedPassword" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ChangedPassword)
        </div>

        <div class="col_full">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ConfirmPassword, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "capitalize t600" })
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ConfirmPassword, null, new { @class = "sm-form-control", id = "txtConfirmPassword" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ConfirmPassword)
        </div>

        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
            <input type="submit" value="Save Changes" class="btn btn-primary" id="updatePassword()"/>

        </div>
    </div>
}
```

and I have a cshtml that invokes this partial view in a modal.

```
@model WebApplication1.Models.DB.SysUser
<div class="modal fade" id="modalPassword" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-

labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                            <div class="modal-dialog">
                                <div class="modal-body">
                                    <div class="modal-content">
                                        <div id="message"></div>
                                        <div class="modal-header">
                                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                                            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Change Password</h4>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="modal-body">
                                            @*<p class="nobottommargin">@Html.Action("InvokeChangePassword", "Account")</p>*@
                                            <p class="nobottommargin">
                                                @{
                                                    @Html.RenderPartial("ChangePassword", ); <----- HOW TO USE RENDER PARTIAL
                                                }
                                            </p>

                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

I will be using the modal to update the password. Since it doesn't allow me to use `@Html.RenderPartial("ChangePassword")`, how can I use the `@Html.RenderPartial()` when it needs an object of `ChangeUserPassword` as its model? Thank you.

Comment: Post your ChangePassword method

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use renderpartial, add the model you want to pass to the partial view inside the main model.

example: 
If you want `SysUser` and `ChangeUserPassword`, then add a main model which contains both this class.

```
Public class MainModel{
public SysUser suser {get;set;}
public ChangeUserPassword cup {get;set;}
}
```

Then pass the main model inside the main view and pass ChangeUserPassword  like below:

```
@model WebApplication1.Models.MainModel
<div class="modal fade" id="modalPassword" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-

labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                            <div class="modal-dialog">
                                <div class="modal-body">
                                    <div class="modal-content">
                                        <div id="message"></div>
                                        <div class="modal-header">
                                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                                            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Change Password</h4>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="modal-body">
                                            @*<p class="nobottommargin">@Html.Action("InvokeChangePassword", "Account")</p>*@
                                            <p class="nobottommargin">
                                                @{
                  Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Users/_ChangePassword.cshtml", Model.cup);
                                                }
                                            </p>

                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Note: Change the path and names according to your need.

Comment: I actually did what you have adviced. In my begin form, it points to my ChangePassword which saves the necessary update. Why is it that when I purposely make a mistake on oldpassword or even if I successfully updated the password, it gives me a blank page and in  my URL it says" "http://localhost:19147/Account/ChangePassword"? If I make my ChangePassword to return a partial View, it gives me the raw partial view like just the label and 3 input boxes not the view where I came from.

Comment: I can't even see my validation summary if I do not return a partial view. But if I create a partial view, I will see the validation summary without any css and _layout.

Comment: @lbanez1408 How did you add css file to the partial view?

Comment: @Ibanez1408 What you are returning from ChangePassword method? Post that code? If it's an Html.BeginForm it will redirect your entire page and when you return the partial view you won't css and layout.